# Software testing between two applications (Desktop and Mobile)

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, testing, mobile, metrics

I'm developing a mobile application for WP7 based on an existing Silverlight desktop application. I want to perform a test comparison between both applications concerning the user interaction and experience.
I known that exists several software testing methods. But none of them fit in what I really want to test, which is having the right metrics to perform the comparison.
Right now I believe that Usability Testing is the closest from what I want that is:

- Compare the way of performing similar actions
- Compare the degree of similarity
- The adaptability capacity of using the mobile app against the desktop application

Sorry for the weird question :P
And thank you in advance...

Comment: I agree that usability is the closest thing you have to get some metrics but these metrics should probably be done by humans; I do not think you will be able to automate this at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tests you describe are all very subjective.
I don't see any approach other than testing manually.